# How can I figure out which valves should be open?

Tags: water, pool

Just had my DE filter replaced with a cartridge filter.  The pipes going to the motor have three valves.  Since the replacement I am losing water and can't remember which of the valves should be open and which should be closed.  I believe one is for the vacuum system which I don't need, one is for the skimmer, and one for the main drain (can't remember which is which though).  The two valves on the right regulate whether I am using the returns or the in-ground cleaning system. I have no problem with that.

[image]

Comment: Where do the two pipes on the right go?

Comment: Those two go to the returns and the in ground cleaning system.

Comment: Hi @user21223! It looks like you’ve accidentally created a couple of accounts. If you’d like to merge them (there are some [advantages](http://diy.stackexchange.com/help/why-register) to doing so), the instructions are [here](http://diy.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 1):

Losing water? As in your water level is going down? That is not a problem with valve position. You've got a leak somewhere and a professional needs to address that.